# Retrieving Raw_Input from a system ran script

Tags: python, jython

I'm using the OS.System command to call a python script.

example:

```
OS.System("call jython script.py")
```

In the script I'm calling, the following command is present:

```
x = raw_input("Waiting for input")
```

If I run script.py from the command line I can input data no problem, if I run it via the automated approach I get an EOFError.  I've read in the past that this happens because the system expects a computer to be running it and therefore could never receive input data in this way.

So the question is how can I get python to wait for user input while being run in an automated way?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you run your child script. Since you use os.system() the script's input channel is closed immediately and the raw_input() prompt hits an EOF (end of file). And even if that didn't happen, you wouldn't have a way to actually send some input text to the child as I assume you'd want given that you are using raw_input().

You should use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

p = subprocess.Popen(["jython", "script.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
print p.communicate("My input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.  What is the process calling your Python script and how is it being run?  If the parent process has no standard input, the child won't have it either.